# (your) suggested edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request

How do I get a list of all of my suggested edits across the stack exchange network?

On the stackexchange user panel e.g. https://stackexchange.com/users/4338618/mpag?tab=accounts, you CAN search all your Questions, Answers and comments, but there is no GET URI for seeing suggestion history like on the sub-sites (?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

e.g.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/52150/mpag?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Answer (score 2):

The following query on data.se allows for a user to see all accepted, rejected and pending suggested edits. As SE <strike>appears to</strike> use**s** MSSQL, this seems an appropriate forum.

http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/752249/users-suggested-edits

I hope someone else finds it useful

Code paste:

```
-- My accepted/rejected/pending edits
-- Shows all my suggested edits
-- Returns all non-Meta StackExchange sites
-- Username searches are case-sensitive

 EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @precommand='CREATE TABLE ##fooj (Site nvarchar(150), [Site UserID] nvarchar(75), [Suggested Edit Link]  nvarchar(255), [Accepted?]  nvarchar(10), [Post Link]  nvarchar(75), comment  Text, [Creation Date]  DateTime, [Decision Date] DateTime)', 
 @postcommand='BEGIN 
 SELECT * from ##fooj order by [Creation Date] DESC
 DROP TABLE ##fooj
 END', 
 @command1='USE [?] BEGIN 
IF (DB_Name() NOT IN (''master'', ''tempdb'', ''model'', ''msdb'') and DB_Name() NOT LIKE ''Meta.%'' and DB_Name() NOT LIKE ''%.Meta'') BEGIN 
With sn as (SELECT
PARSENAME(DB_Name(),1)+''.''+COALESCE(PARSENAME(DB_Name(),2),'''')+''.''+COALESCE(PARSENAME(DB_Name(),3),'''')+''.''+COALESCE(PARSENAME(DB_Name(),4),'''') aS SiteName
), sitesnames as (SELECT
LEFT(SiteName,LEN(SiteName)+1-patindex(''%[A-Za-z]%'', reverse(SiteName)) ) as SiteName
from sn
), sites as (SELECT
SiteName,
''https://''+SiteName+''.com/'' as SiteURL,
''https://''+SiteName+''.com/users/'' as UserBase,
''https://''+SiteName+''.com/a/'' as PostBase,
''https://''+SiteName+''.com/suggested-edits/'' as SugBase
from sitesnames
)
INSERT INTO ##fooj
SELECT ''''+sites.SiteURL+''|''+sites.SiteName, --''''https://''+DB_Name()+''.com |''+DB_Name()+'''',
''''+sites.UserBase+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(250),e.OwnerUserID)+''|''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(250),e.OwnerUserID)+'''', 
       ''''+sites.SugBase+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(250),e.id)+''|Suggestion #''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(250),e.id)+'''' [Suggested Edit Link],
       CASE WhEN ApprovalDate>0 THEN ''Accepted'' WHEn RejectionDate>0 THEN ''Rejected'' ELSE ''Pending'' END as [Accept | Reject],
       ''''+sites.PostBase+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(250),e.PostId)+''|''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(250),e.PostId)+'''' as [Post Link], 
       e.Comment, 
       e.CreationDate, 
       COALESCE(RejectionDate,e.ApprovalDate) as DecisionDate
       from sites CROSS JOIN ([?]..SuggestedEdits as e join [?]..Users as U on e.OwnerUserID = U.ID)
WHErE U.DisplayName=''##DisplayName##''
--order by COALESCE(e.RejectionDate,e.ApprovalDate) desc 
END END'
```

Comment: Not seems to, does. That's actually published info, and I believe the source code is probably open source, but don't quote me on that ... ;-) https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer

Comment: note that there is a delay in the update of data queriable from data.stackexchange relative to what is made available to the actual user interface.  It took a few days for one of my rejected revisions to make it into the list generated by this query.

Comment: I thought that was publicized on the site ... but I don't see it on http://data.stackexchange.com/help ... I've just been around the network way too long to remember what's tribal and what's written knowledge

Comment: the update delay is noted in the FAQ on that link: Frequently Asked Questions

How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?
    The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was Nov 5 at 7:12.  that being said, I didn't bother looking at the help :P

Comment: My brain didn't see that hahahahaha